# How to list specific contain value in dropdown jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of name, but I just want to display certain value that contain of specific word, doesn't matter have space or not in that list of name.

For example I want to list only that contain `York` & `zil` both in same dropdown list:

1. NewYork
2. New York
3. Australia
4. Brazil

I have tried below but not working.

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response){
        if (response.result == "success"){
            $.each(response.node, function(key, value){

                // 1st option - not working
                if ((value.name.indexOf('PED') > -1) || (value.name.indexOf('PEM') > -1) || (value.name.indexOf('PAG') > -1) || (value.name.indexOf('PCO') > -1)){
                    $('#source').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.node_id).text(value.name));
                }

                // 2nd option - only working if I enable 1st `IF` below, but if I enable 2nd, 3rd and 4th `IF`, then it is not working at all.
                if (value.name.indexOf('PED') > -1){
                    $('#source').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.node_id).text(value.name));
                }
                if (value.name.indexOf('PEM') > -1){
                    $('#source').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.node_id).text(value.name));
                }
                if (value.name.indexOf('PAG') > -1){
                    $('#source').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.node_id).text(value.name));
                }
                if (value.name.indexOf('PCO') > -1){
                    $('#source').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.node_id).text(value.name));
                }
            });
        }
        else {}
    },
    error: function(){}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet work well for `I want to list only that contain York & zil both in same dropdown list`

```js
        var node = [{ name: 'NewYork', node_id: 1 }, { name: 'New York', node_id: 2 }, { name: 'Australia', node_id: 3 }, { name: 'Brazil', node_id: 4 }]

        $.each(node, function (key, value) {

            if (value.name.includes('York') ||                 value.name.includes('zil')) {
                $('#source').append($('<option>', {
                    value: value.node_id,
                    text: value.name
                }));
            }
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <select id="source">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get every element in the array that has a value that contains York or zil.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var countries = ["NewYork", "New York", "Australia", "Brazil"];

function checkCounty(country) {
    return country.indexOf("York") !== -1 || country.indexOf("zil") !== -1;
}

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = countries.filter(checkCounty);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```